# Get MongoDB driver version programmatically

Tags: java, mongodb, version, mongo-java-driver

I am using the MongoDriver as external JBOSS module. 
I am looking for a way to programmatically detect which driver version I am actually using.
For clarity sake, I wish to do something such as:

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient(...).getDriverVersion();
// Returns something such as 3.8.2
```

How can I do that? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String mongoVersion  = MongoDriverVersion.VERSION;
```

Comment: Well, that was easy!

Comment: Is that official API? The package is `com.mongodb.internal.build`.